# JIRA SDK C# - cannot save value for CustomField

Tags: c#, .net-core, sdk, jira

My code below for some reason doesn't work as intended. It looks like using "equal" to set value for Value of CustomField simply don't change... did somebody has similar problem?

```
public async void doSomething(string issueNumber){
    var issue = await inner_client.Issues.GetIssueAsync(issueNumber); //getting issue

    var valueOfChangedField = issue["Bramki"].Value;

    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(dupsqwe.Value)
    
    //something is done here to modify object myDeserializedClass and below we change it back to json to put in issue["Bramki"].Value
    
    string modifiedTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDeserializedClass); //serializing to JSON NEW to be used as new value
    
    issue["Bramki"].Value = modifiedTable; //setting new value
    var test = issue["Bramki"].Value;      // added later but show that value isn't changed...

    await issue.SaveChangesAsync(); // saving changes
}
```

Comment: what is your error message?

Answer (score 2):

Please test with this block code and if your problem will not solve please add your error message in your question.

```
public async void doSomething(string issueNumber){

            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(dupsqwe.Value)
    
            //something is done here to modify object myDeserializedClass and below we change it back to json to put in issue["Bramki"].Value
    
            string modifiedTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDeserializedClass); //serializing to JSON NEW to be used as new value
    
            var newIssue = jira.Issues.GetIssueAsync(issueNumber).Result;

            newIssue["Custom Text Field"] = modifiedTable;//"My new value";
            newIssue["Custom Date Field"] = modifiedTable;//"2015-10-03";
            newIssue.CustomFields.AddArray("Custom Labels Field", modifiedTable);
            newIssue.CustomFields.AddArray("Custom Multi Group Field", modifiedTable, "modifiedTable2");
            newIssue.CustomFields.AddCascadingSelectField("Custom Cascading Select Field", modifiedTable, "modifiedTable2");

            newIssue.SaveChanges();
            
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad,

thanks, your solution worked for me. I stripped it down to:

                jira_issue["CustomFieldName123"] = "Value123";
                jira_issue.SaveChanges();

I've tried something like this before but it didn't work. Once SaveChanges() the value in my debugger watch list would immediately revert and no changes were applied:

                var tmp = jira_issue.CustomFields["CustomFieldName123"];
                tmp.Values[0] = "Value123";
                jira_issue.SaveChanges();

PS: Any idea on how I can update the Assignee and Reporter?
But that